# How prevent user updating in Angular Satellizer

Tags: angularjs, token, twitter-oauth, facebook-access-token, satellizer

I have one problem. I using [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) in my Angular App. And I only want to grab user token after succesful authentication in social newtworks. But after succesfull authorizhation server sends me user object and Satelizer update 
user object on client. Could you help me? How can I solve this problem in Angular Saterlizer or I need some changes in my server?

Comment: please add your code in to the question